# JSON Parsing using Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, soap

I am calling a soap service in my application. I am getting this response in JSON from server

```
{  
  "CustomerName":"Muneer Ahmad/ Ejaz Ahmad (User)  ",
  "IsCorporate":false,
  "ID":48,
  "Name":"Muneer Ahmad/ Ejaz Ahmad (User)  ",
  "GroupID":null,
  "GroupName":null,
  "CustomerID":48
}
```

I have tried what online tutorial suggests but I am not able to parse data. It gives me error that "Invalid value around character 0." My Code is this

```
 let is_URL: String = "http://labs2.unitedtracker.com/WTService.asmx?op=GetTerminalNumber"

    let lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: is_URL)! as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    lobj_Request.httpMethod = "POST"
    lobj_Request.httpBody = is_SoapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    lobj_Request.addValue("labs2.unitedtracker.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    lobj_Request.addValue(String(is_SoapMessage.characters.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    lobj_Request.addValue("http://tempuri.org/GetTerminalNumber", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: lobj_Request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        do {
            if let data = data,
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],
                let customerID = json["CustomerID"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                print(customerID)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
        }

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error: " + String(describing: error))
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong i m doing. And how should be such JSON response from Soap Service should be parsed.

Here is complete response from my Server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetAuthenticateUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetAuthenticateUserResult>[{"CustomerName":"Muneer Ahmad/ Ejaz Ahmad (User)  ","IsCorporate":false,"ID":48,"Name":"Muneer Ahmad/ Ejaz Ahmad (User)  ","GroupID":null,"GroupName":null,"CustomerID":48}]</GetAuthenticateUserResult></GetAuthenticateUserResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Where do you receive the error, in the `catch` handler? Can you log the incoming `data` as a string?

Comment: No! I am getting error out of catch handler. When I am trying to print customerID it says this that "Invalid value around character 0."

Comment: Why do you parse customerID as an array of dictionaries? Looking at the JSON response, customerID is clearly an Int, so you should parse it like so. `let customerID = json["CustomerID"] as? Int {
                print(customerID)
            }`

Comment: Good point raised @David Pasztor Actually it's a string value. I try what you said.

Comment: So apparently the server response is XML and not JSON.

Comment: look a view when you are free https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON to help us deal with JSON data in Swift in a more readable way. Optional unwrapping is handled automatically for you as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

How do you guarantee that server will return `json` as response ? It seems like that it will return `text/xml` as response.

About JSON parsing, I suggest [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

#### More suggesions

Years ago, I had use a soap client engine, it will parse `wsdl` to `objective-c` codes. Today, maybe some tools could help you to generate `Swift` codes from `wsdl` in order to communicate with soap server.

#### About wsdl to swift client generator

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32798709/419348
  The author had post answer about wsdltoswift.
- http://wsdl2swift.com wsdl2swift url.

Comment: The JSON in beginning is the string I m receiving from server. We can see that it is in JSON format.

Comment: As @zoul 's comment, could you log the incoming `data` as a string ?

Comment: I have updated my question and full response from server is also in it now

Comment: Obviously, `<xml version ... >` is `xml` format, not `json`. I had updated my answers. Maybe survey some wsdl parsing tool could help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you receive XML from the server and try to parse it as JSON. You have to extract the JSON payload from the XML envelope first. This is the whole response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAuthenticateUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetAuthenticateUserResult>[{"CustomerName":"Muneer Ahmad/ Ejaz Ahmad (User)  ","IsCorporate":false,"ID":48,"Name":"Muneer Ahmad/ Ejaz Ahmad (User)  ","GroupID":null,"GroupName":null,"CustomerID":48}]</GetAuthenticateUserResult>
    </GetAuthenticateUserResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

You need to extract the contents of the `<GetAuthenticateUserResult>` tag as a string and *only then* you can use `NSJSONSerialization` to parse that. A bit like this:

```
class Extractor: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {

    var payload = ""
    private var recording = false
    let wantedElement = "GetAuthenticateUserResult"

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?,
        qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        if elementName == wantedElement {
            recording = true
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if recording {
            payload += string
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        recording = false
    }
}

let response = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><GetAuthenticateUserResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><GetAuthenticateUserResult>[{\"CustomerName\":\"Muneer Ahmad/ Ejaz Ahmad (User)\",\"IsCorporate\":false,\"ID\":48,\"Name\":\"Muneer Ahmad/ Ejaz Ahmad (User)  \",\"GroupID\":null,\"GroupName\":null,\"CustomerID\":48}]</GetAuthenticateUserResult></GetAuthenticateUserResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
let parser = XMLParser(data: response.data(using: .utf8)!)
let extractor = Extractor()
parser.delegate = extractor
parser.parse()
let payload = extractor.payload
let parsedPayload = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: payload.data(using: .utf8)!, options: [])
```

That gives you:

```
{
    CustomerID = 48;
    CustomerName = "Muneer Ahmad/ Ejaz Ahmad (User)";
    GroupID = "<null>";
    GroupName = "<null>";
    ID = 48;
    IsCorporate = 0;
    Name = "Muneer Ahmad/ Ejaz Ahmad (User)  ";
}
```

The XML extraction code is a bit stupid since I don’t know any better built-in XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
let customerID = json["CustomerID"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    print(customerID)
}
```

treats the `customerID` as dictionary instead of string.

It should be:

```
let customerID = json["CustomerID"] as? String {
    print(customerID)
}
```

You should use another way of network request and JSON parser, like [Alamofire and AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper).

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is you wrapping `String` to `[[String:Any]]`

Instead of this:

```
if let data = data,
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],
    let customerID = json["CustomerID"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        print(customerID)
}
```

try this:

```
if let data = data,
   let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]],
   let customerID = json["CustomerID"] as? String {
       print(customerID)
}
```

Comment: `customerId` looks like a number in the JSON response: `"CustomerID":48`. So maybe `let customerID = json["CustomerID"] as? Int` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Bala Karunakaran I am still getting error. "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." I think I should try with allowing fragments

Comment: @MattLeFleur I have tried it.  if let data = data,
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any],
                        let customerID = json["CustomerID"] as? Int { print(customerID) }. But still no luck. Giving me same error of invalid character.

Comment: instead of [String: Any] try with [[String: Any]]